# How to make active wifi scanner with Pi

Tags: pi-3, wifi, logfiles

I am looking for developing a device based on Rasp pi3 which can detect wifi probe requests with logging device spec data such as MAC, SSID and timestamp
Any help??

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install aircrack-ng package, and use a command like `sudo airodump-ng -i wlan0 -w /dev/shm/scan --uptime --output-format=csv,netxml -c 1-14`. I believe the default write interval is 60 seconds, it may be lowered with a flag. Parse the files as you please, it makes more sense to use python for that than for scanning (though scapy is awesome).

Answer (score 0):

Just yesterday I did that. I did not completed because I went to sleep but seems to work. Download and install Kali Linux on an SDCard and then sniff network traffic with wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, as I did, with the Python 'wifi' library. It is un-maintained, but works well. [Read about the wifi library here](https://github.com/rockymeza/wifi)

To install:

```
sudo pip install wifi
```

Then, in Python:

```
# Import the library
from wifi import Cell, Scheme

# Define a function which adds a summary attribute (this isn't necessary but was handy for my purposes)
def scanForCells():
    # Scan using wlan0
    cells = Cell.all('wlan0')

    # Loop over the available cells
    for cell in cells:
        cell.summary = 'SSID {} / Quality {}'.format(cell.ssid, cell.quality)

        if cell.encrypted:
            enc_yes_no = '*'
        else:
            enc_yes_no = '()'

        cell.summary = cell.summary + ' / Encryption {}'.format(enc_yes_no)

    return cells


cells = scanForCells()
for cell in cells:
    print(cell.summary)
```

[Other attributes to get out of the cell are available here](https://github.com/rockymeza/wifi/blob/master/docs/scanning.rst)

[Code taken from my own project](https://github.com/recantha/handheldPi)

You will need to run it as 'sudo' as it parses the output from iwlist which only returns other networks as a super-user, so:

```
sudo python <filename>.py
```